# Dynamic Content not getting resolved after publish?

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, dynamic-linking, linking

I am reading all Components through the `Core Service` for updating an anchor tag to a TCM URI. After a successful update, when I publish the Page containing the respective Component the TCM URI doesn't get resolved to a proper URL.

But when I make any change in this Component in the CME and save it, when the Page is published again, the link does get resolved to a proper URL.

I wonder why is this happening? Is there any solution for this?

Previously I had `<a href="abc/xyc/aboutus.aspx">...</a>` anchor tag, after updating it becomes `<a href="tcm:22-20314">...</a>`. This is a Components TCM URI and this Component is attached in `aboutus.aspx`.

Comment: What do you mean "updating the anchor tag to tcm Id"? and after updating by coreservice, do you see desired results in component?

Comment: yes I am able to see the desired results. Updating anchor tag means adding component's tcm id into href property by replacing url.

Comment: Can you post your anchore tag here. how it's getting formed after updating the component.

Comment: previously I have "a href="abc/xyc/aboutus.aspx""anchor tag after updating it becomes "a href="tcm:22-20314"" this is a component's tcm and this component is attached in aboutus.aspx

Comment: @pankaj Your question is very vague and does not contain useful context information, you could consider adding a code sample from your Core Service application. 

Also instead of replying to a comment via another comment, you can better edit and update your question, so this information is clear for everybody. If you are asked for additional information or a clarification and you don't edit and update your question, you will not get many relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're publishing components with a dynamic template and your links are not resolved, but they are resolved when publishing in a page, then probably what's happening is that the `Link Resolver` TBB is not available in your Component Template.

Add this TBB (or better yet, the `Default Finish Actions` TBB) to the end of your Component Template and try publishing again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a Dynamic Link your anchor should be:

```
<a tridion:href="tcm:x-x-x">...</a>
```

and your PT or CT should contain the Link Resolver Template Building Block.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of issue. I have added `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.try adding it in your anchor tag while updating the component.It may solve your problem